# Rails: 2 where queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuggling with this line of code:

```
Warehouse.where(:product => self.product).pluck(:mrr).sum.round(2)
```

But the thing is if a product is named twice the app does not now which one to pick. So I tried something like this:

```
Warehouse.where(:product => self.product)
         .where(:company => self.order.brand)
         .pluck(:mrr).sum.round(2)
```

But then I get this error:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column warehouses.company does not exist LINE 1: ...warehouses" WHERE "warehouses"."product" = $1 AND "warehouse... ^ : SELECT "warehouses"."mrr" FROM "warehouses" WHERE "warehouses"."product" = $1 AND "warehouses"."company" = ‘Adidas’

The query should actually look up the productname and the corresponding brand and then pull the price.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "warehouses", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "category"
 t.text     "product"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 t.string   "brand"
 t.text     "period1"
 t.text     "period2"
 t.string   "producttype"
 t.decimal  "mrr"
 t.decimal  "suf"
 t.decimal  "discount"
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please ass the db schema for the tables involved. And note, the query looks for "column warehouses.company" I would assume product has the company column.

Comment: Do you have `company` column in `warehouses` table?

Comment: What do you mean, "product is named twice"?

Comment: I edited the DB scheme. I mean That a product can be in the DB twice with same names but different prices.

Comment: Well if there are more warehouses with the same product, of course it picks all of them. What is your goal? Do you only want to pick a certain warehouse?

Comment: And where does `self.order` come from? A relation? A method? A param?

Comment: Your warehouse table does not have a `company` field, hence the `.where(company: self.order.brand)` query is invalid.

Comment: @TheCha͢mp that's it! Thanks very much!

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to achieve... But if that was the only problem you can delete this question, it's only a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see what the ERROR say in vary first line

```
ERROR: column warehouses.company does not exist
```